# QtSql create mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, qt, qtsql

Is there a way to connect to the database server without specifying a database?

I would like to be able to create a database if it's missing - but the QtSql drivers require some database to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your database server also requires that.

By default MySQL has a database called "mysql" which you can use as a default though.

Comment: somehow mysql commandline client can issue "create database" without being connected to a database.. do you mean it connects to "mysql" by default anyways?